# Resized Partition now Windows startup error

Tags: windows-7, boot, chkdsk

I installed Windows 7 on a new partition then tried to wipe out my old Vista partition. After I finally was able to resize my new partition to the whole disk using Gparted, Windows won't boot up anymore. The Windows recovery won't recognize my installation, and neither will bootrec. When I try to boot up, I get an error that \Boot\BCD is corrupt and that I should run chkdsk. But, when I run that, I get an error that the disk is locked.

Am I up the creek without a paddle? If necessary, I can throw my HDD into a case, get my data off then reinstall Windows, but I'd like to try a recovery if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (at your own risk):

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

**TestDisk** is powerful free data recovery software! It was primarily designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software, certain types of viruses or human error (such as accidentally deleting a Partition Table). Partition table recovery using TestDisk is really easy.

Comment: Thank you! TestDisk restored the partition but I still got a startup error. Fortunately, TestDisk made it so that I could throw my HDD into an enclosure and get my data off. I guess I'll have to reinstall Windows (again), but at least my data is safe!

Answer (score 2):

Boot from the W7 dvd, and [do a startup repair](http://www.trishtech.com/win7/using_startup_repair_to_fix_boot_problems_in_windows_7.php), it may take up to 3 repairs in a row to get it booting again.

[Another Method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392/en-us)